# Why aiohttp not allows colon in url path?

Tags: python, http, telegram-bot, aiohttp

I am creating a telegram bot that gets an updates via webhook. 
So, i am successfully registered the webhook with url looks like:

```
https://my-app.herokuapp.com/123456789:aglbfiwefiuwehwelf  # url with fake token
```

And then i added a route to handle an update:

```
app.router.add_route('POST', '/123456789:aglbfiwefiuwehwelf', webhook)
```

The bot hosted on heroku and when i run it, i see a 404 error in a heroku log. I tested it locally and i found out that aiohttp not resolves the url with colon. I solved this problem by using a variable 
`app.router.add_route('POST', '/{token}', webhook)`, but i am interested in why actually aiohttp not allows a colon in url path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub you can go through the Blame history to see the commits that changed a specific part of the codebase.

1. Initially it was only checked to not be None in [85668a](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/85668ad24637ce626591209f41d0e6d3fdfacd27#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR296).
2. This was however too relaxed, and so there was a limitation set to only accept Python identifiers in [a2aa20](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/a2aa20dacbeb34544cc69765e20dabe5718c0d57#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR448).
3. Then it seems that more relaxation was needed, so [98e3a9](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/98e3a9181d7b3264d7ebd7955a01ba9a08df9dc3#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR392) made the rule more relax by adding splitters for dot and colons. This was version 0.18.1.
4. Next up dashes were added [8cc211](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/8cc211adc3f36af12898c6beca2ac6b701de0a0b#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR392).
5. Finally underscores were allowed as well [3fd3d6](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/3fd3d6a8b52306c6ad7a78fe8859e7b42fc12893#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR702)

So from 0.18.1 on, colons are allowed. I advise you to upgrade your aiohttp dependency.

Another note, I am not 100% sure if you can use brackets in your url pattern see [85668a](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/85668ad24637ce626591209f41d0e6d3fdfacd27#diff-b41dc5c66bc19f22fe7cc77c002db02cR335).